# Determine path to source code of current mode in Emacs 23

Tags: emacs, path, mode, python-mode

I'm trying out a new Python mode for Emacs 23, but I'm not sure how to tell if I'm using the new mode (source code located at `~/.elisp/python.el`) or the bundled `python.el` mode.

Is there a way to find out where the current (or any active) mode was loaded from? <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> does not seem to provide that information, and I don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `python-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> will tell you which file it lives in, and you can browse to that file by following the link.

You can also use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `python-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> to go there directly.

(I find it handy to have `find-function` bound to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>)

In general, you could use the following:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(find-function major-mode)` <kbd>RET</kbd>